# Organize a hash of hashes by values in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash format like this:

```
{"string1" => 
  {date1 => 1, 
   date2 => 21, 
   date3 => 9},
"string2" =>
  {date1 => 23,
   date2 => 88,
   date3 => 2},
"string3" =>
  {date1 => 0,
   date2 => 0,
   date3 => 5}
}
```

It tells me: "This string, on this date, happened this many times." I'd like to reorder it like this:

```
{date1 =>
 {"string1" => 1,
  "string2" => 23},
date2 =>
 {"string1" => 21,
  "string2" => 88},
date3 => 
 {"string1" => 9,
  "string2" => 2,
  "string3" => 5}
}
```

So now it tells me: "On this date, this string happened this many times".  It's possible that certain dates will have many strings with counts and other dates might have 0 strings with counts. In the end, whatever strings occurred on a given date should appear in the hash.

I'm sure there's a very elegant ruby way. Please help!

Comment: How would a date have 0 strings with counts? If a date appears in the original nested hash, it has an associated string (key), hasn't it?

Comment: not necessarily. This is from a 3rd party service where you give a date range and get results back. So for each string, the whole date range is included, often with many 0s

Comment: You mean that when you have `{"string1" => {date1 => 0}}`, `string1` should not appear in the values of the resulting `date1` key? So how do you end up with `date1 => {"string1" => 0}` in your sample?

Comment: you're right. let me edit the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you want.

```
h = {"string1" => {"date1" => 1,  "date2" => 21, "date3" => 9},
     "string2" => {"date1" => 23, "date2" => 88, "date3" => 2},
     "string3" => {"date1" => 0,  "date2" => 0,  "date3" => 5}}

h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g| v.each { |d,vv|
  (g[d] ||= {}).update({ k=>vv }) } }
  #=> {"date1"=>{"string1"=>1,  "string2"=>23, "string3"=>0},
  #    "date2"=>{"string1"=>21, "string2"=>88, "string3"=>0},
  #    "date3"=>{"string1"=>9,  "string2"=>2,  "string3"=>5}}
```

If you don't want the pairs with value zero, do this first:

```
h.each { |k,v| v.delete_if { |_,vv| vv.zero? } }
  #=> {"string1"=>{"date1"=>1, "date2"=>21, "date3"=>9},
  #    "string2"=>{"date1"=>23, "date2"=>88, "date3"=>2},
  #    "string3"=>{"date3"=>5}}

h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g| v.each { |d,vv|
  (g[d] ||= {}).update({ k=>vv }) } }
  #=> {"date1"=>{"string1"=>1,  "string2"=>23},
  #    "date2"=>{"string1"=>21, "string2"=>88},
  #    "date3"=>{"string1"=>9,  "string2"=>2, "string3"=>5}}
```

I've made `datex` a string. If they were `Date` objects (or symbols, etc.), the expression would be no different.

Comment: I ended up using a do block for sanity and got rid of 0 entries and entries with empty strings with this:
`hash.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), subhash|
  next if key == ""
  value.each do |k, v| 
    (subhash[k] ||= {}).update({ key => v }) if v > 0
  end
end
`

Comment: @cheeseandpepper Note that with this answer (or your updated code), you won't get the empty dates required in the OP (`date6 => {}`). But maybe that's now OK for you.

Comment: @PatriceGahide, if there are other key/value pairs to delete, the block for `v.delete_if` could be accordingly (e.g, `{ |_,vv| vv.zero? || vv.empty? }`).

Comment: Yes, never mind,  I think the OP changed something in his last edit. At some point he wanted "empty dates" (`date=>{}`) to appear in the resulting hash. That doesn't seem to be true anymore.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  Empty hashes are not important so neither Date => {} nor "String" => {} matter for me.  Though I appreciate seeing the differences in the examples

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it:

```
res = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = {} }
hash.each do |kstring, datehash|
  datehash.each { |kdate, n| n == 0 ? res[kdate] : res[kdate][kstring] = n }
end
```

Comment: this was closer to my initial attempt - I wanted to make a new hash with an initial value of 0 and recalculate the count values. Nicely done with this!